# Identify the bike/frame NS alike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I got this bike, but I doubt it is NS bike since only Movement or Decade could be similar, but still there are differences.

[image]

Edit: Yes bike was painted and its just a NS sticker

Comment: 2 thoughts:  First, if it's been repainted then components might have been swapped out too; and second, is there a reason that it's important to know what it is?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles. We recommend that new members take the [tour] to make best use of the site. Here is a description of how to post a bike ID question with the best chance of getting an answer. https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1337/how-do-i-ask-a-good-id-my-bike-question

Comment: Yes, it appears that the frame have been repainted. It is being sold as a Dirt jump, the reason to know what is this frame is if we can call it dirt jump and if its safe, if it was NS frame we could say so, or atleast some known brand, not just noname.